# Operations on Collections: Naming, Reference, Linq to Objects Library

Tags: collections, naming-conventions, linq-to-objects

I'm finding myself writing more and more Linq to Objects (L2O) extension methods
to encapsulate operations on collections (IEnumerable/ICollection/IList).

For guidelines I often peek at [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListManipulation.html) which has a very complete and 
powerful set of list manipulation functions.

Some functions they have are the same as in L2O e.g.
`Reverse`, `Take`, `First`, `Last`
Some differ slightly: `Skip` is called `Drop`.
Besides them are a ton of operations not provided by the BCL.

**1. Is there an existing free and OSS L2O library that compares to the Mathematica list operations?**
(I know [moreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) and [LinqExtLibrary](http://linqlib.codeplex.com/), both of which are comparatively limited)

**2. Is there a standard terminology for operations on collections?**
(de facto standard names like for the Design Patterns by the GOF)

**3. Is there a good reference for operations on collections?**

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer #1, but for #2 and #3, I think you might be interested in **[101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)** on MSDN.

Some terminology they use include:

#### Restriction, Projection, Partitioning, Ordering, Grouping, Set, Conversion, Element, Generation, Quantifiers, Aggregate, Join

The above link is also a great reference with code samples for each operation.  If you're interested in the inner workings, [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) wrote a brilliant blog series called [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) that basically discusses the entire design of LINQ from beginning to end.